# Scalding + LZO +Protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, lzo, scalding

Are there any pointers to get Scalding to work with LZO Protobuf data on HDFS?

I am trying to read files that are stored in binary Protobuf and compressed in LZO using Scalding. 
Can we use Elephantbird to read those files? Any pointers will be appreciated!

I have looked at the LzoTraits and LzoProtobufScheme? But I am not sure how I should be using it to read the data? Any examples would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
case class SomeProto() extends FixedPathSource("/my/greatData/*")
  with LzoProtobuf[MyProtoClassHere] {
    override def column = classOf[MyProtoClassHere]
}
```

You can mix with other types of abstract base Sources (like TimePathedSource, or MostRecentGoodSource) in a similar way.  You can mix in `with LocalTapSource` if you want to use the Hadoop-inside-cascading-local trick (if you don't run in cascading local mode, you don't need this).

Comment: Thanks, Will the same class also work for writing out Lzo compressed protobuf files?

Comment: Another quick followup question. How do I read binary protobuf files that are not lzo compressed?